# Как в ивенте on_raw_reaction_add получить имя пользователя, написавшего сообщение

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Я делаю discord бота(discord.py) и мне нужна функция которая будет прибавляет к полю xp в бд 500, если сообщение пользователя было помечено реакцией ''. Я пытался сделать это, и вот что у меня получилось:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    """Функция on_raw_reaction_add прибавляет к полю xp в бд 500,
    если сообщение пользователя было помечено реакцией ''.
    """
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
    if payload.member.id == 633717285474795557 and str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET xp = xp + 500 WHERE id = {payload.member}")
        connect.commit()
```

Но эта функция прибавляет 500 автору реакции, а мне нужно чтобы добавляла автору сообщения. Помогите плз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что member - человек, который добавил реакцию.
Вам же нужно прибавлять значение 500 к XP автору message, а не автору реакции:

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET xp = xp + 500 WHERE id = {message.author}")
```

Если решение не подойдет, то возможно стоит объединить вашу функцию с чем-то подобным:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author